# regex capture with g modifier captures only first occurrence

Tags: regex, ecmascript-6

Using EcmaScript 6 RegExp
From this :  "-=Section A=- text A -=Section B=- text b"
I want to get this: ['Section A', 'text A', 'Section B', 'text B']

Apart from the delimiters, everything else is variable. *(Eventually '-=someString=-' will be '' but for now I did not want to clutter things up or create errors with characters that need escaping.)*

I am not a regex expert, but I have searched all day for an example or guidance to make this work without success.

For example using this code:

```
let templateString = "-=Section A=- text A -=Section B=- text b";
let regex = RegExp('-=(.*?)=-(.*?)','g');
```

I only get this: ["-=Section A=-", "Section A", ""]

I am not sure how to make the second of the captures capture 'text A'. Also I do not understand why the g modifier is not making it continue after the first match and go on to find 'Section B' and 'text B'.

Any pointers to some examples would be appreciated - I have failed to find any.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `(.*?)` at the end of the pattern will always match an empty string since it is lazy, and is not executed in the first place. [`text A` cannot be matched](https://regex101.com/r/BSvlg9/1) because the matches ends with `=-`, since `.*?` does not have to be matched.

You may use

```js
let templateString = "-=Section A=- text A -=Section B=- text b";
let regex = /\s*-=(.*?)=-\s*/;
console.log(templateString.split(regex).filter(Boolean));
```

The `\s*-=(.*?)=-\s*` pattern finds

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `-=` - a `-=` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `=-` - a `=-` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

The `String#split` method adds to the resulting array all substrings captured into Group 1.

If you want to use a matching approach, you would need to match any char, 0 or more occurrences, that does not start the leading char sequence, which seems to be `-=` in your scenario:

```js
let templateString = "-=Section A=- text A -=Section B=- text b";
let regex = /-=(.*?)=-\s*([^-]*(?:-(?!=)[^-]*)*)/g;
let m, res=[];
while (m=regex.exec(templateString)) {
   res.push([m[1], m[2].trim()]);
}
console.log(res);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BSvlg9/2)

**Details**

- `-=(.*?)=-\s*` - same as in the first regex (see the split regex above)
- `([^-]*(?:-(?!=)[^-]*)*)` - Group 2 that matches and captures:

  - `[^-]*` - 0+ chars other than `-`
  - `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group that matches

    - `-(?!=)` - a hyphen that is not immediately followed with `=`
    - `[^-]*` - 0+ chars other than `-`
  - `)*` - ...zero or more times